# jq extract value of keypair and assign to bash variable

Tags: json, bash, jq

jq does my head in sometimes. Assume you have a json file called `emails.json` that looks like this;

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "foo1",
    "ParameterValue": "bar1"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "foo2",
    "ParameterValue": "bar2"
  }
]
```

If I run my bash script (let's call it `script.sh`) using the argument foo1, I want to have bar1 assigned to a variable called `emailAdd`. Likewise, if I use the argument foo2, I want bar2 assigned.

I thought my script would look like the following, but I'm getting an empty variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

EMAIL=$1

emailAdd=$(jq --arg email "$EMAIL" '.[] | select(.ParameterKey=="$email") | .ParameterValue' < emails.json)

echo "address is " $emailAdd
```

So, running `sh script.sh foo1` I would expect `address is bar1`, etc

Comment: BTW, if your shebang specifies `bash`, then you shouldn't use `sh script.sh` -- which forces the shebang to be ignored and a baseline-POSIX shell to be used instead. `bash script.sh` is appropriate in that case (though the use of an extension is a bit questionable altogether -- *commands* don't conventionally have extensions on UNIX, after all; you don't run `ls.elf` or `2to3.py` -- and the use of a `.sh` extension for a script that uses a shebang other than `#!/bin/sh` even moreso).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah my bad, forgot to edit it. These scripts are deployed through Jenkins agents, hence the unusual pathing. I always forget to switch things out when testing locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have it correct. You don't need the quotes around `$email`, because unlike shell, `jq` actually treats that as a variable containing a value, rather than something to expand to arbitrary text. You probably also want to use the `-r` option so that the output is `bar1`, rather than `"bar1"`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

EMAIL=$1

emailAdd=$(jq -r --arg email "$EMAIL" '.[] | select(.ParameterKey==$email) | .ParameterValue' < emails.json)

echo "address is $emailAdd"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, and thanks for the explanation!